# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL in PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to write a payment gateway.
I'm getting this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://pgwstest.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

the code that is generating this is:

```
$mclient = new SoapClient('https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl',array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,'trace'=>1));
```

My PHP version is 5.2.17

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is described in the error message you have in your question. The `SoapClient` has a problem to understand the WSDL file.

Comment: @hakre: But the same url is working with `nusoap` and PHP 4, and is working in other gateways that are writen by others!

Comment: WSDL Validation Errors FoundWe were unable to successfully validate the WSDL file at https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl. 
We encountered the following errors:

WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL Retrieval error: Could not obtain data from connection

Comment: You probably find this PHP SOAP library useful, it has more options than the built-in classes: http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/

Answer (score 0):

You've to create stream_context for Mellat Bank in SoapClient object and pass it as 2nd parameter of object I hope it will work fine

```
$stream_context = stream_context_create(
  [
     'ssl' => array(
       'verify_peer'       => false,
       'verify_peer_name'  => false
    )
  ]
);
$your_soap_service_url='https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl';
$soap = new SoapClient($your_soap_service_url,  ['stream_context' => $stream_context]);
```